# has_and_belongs_to_many: how to get correct relations? (JSON output)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I have a `item` model which `belongs_to` a `product` model. 
Each `product` `has_and_belongs_to_many` `specification` models:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items
  has_and_belongs_to_many :specifications
end
```

Relations between `products` and `specifications` are saved within `products_specifications` JOIN Table:

```
  create_table "products_specifications", id: false, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "product_id"
    t.integer "specification_id"
  end
```

[image]

Each `specification` `has_and_belongs_to_many` `tags`:

```
class Specification < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Product Specifications (e.g. Color, Weight, Size, Brand, Product-Type)
  has_and_belongs_to_many :products
  has_and_belongs_to_many :tags # Tags = Spec Detail (e.g. blue, 100 gramm, 5x5x2.5 cm, Apple, Smartphone)
end
```

JOIN Table for `specifications_tags`:

```
  create_table "specifications_tags", id: false, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "specification_id"
    t.integer "tag_id"
  end
```

[image]

And also each `tag` `has_and_belongs_to_many` `specifications`:

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Product Specifications Tag/Details (e.g. blue, 100 gramm, 5x5x2.5 cm, Apple, Smartphone)
  has_and_belongs_to_many :specifications    
end
```

I try to output the item's product with JOIN Table related specifications and JOIN Table related tags like this:

```
  def show
    item = Item.find(params[:id])

    render json: item.to_json(include: {
      product: {include: {specifications: {include: {tags: {}}}}}
    })
  end
```

This does output the correct product model, but it includes all specifications and all tags within the database, instead of only the related ones. The **wrong** JSON Output currently looks simplified like this (for an `item` which belongs to "Apple iPhone 6 Smartphone" `product`):

```
"item":{"id":1,"product":
  {"id":1,"name":"Apple iPhone 6 Smartphone","specifications":
    [
      {"id":1,"name":"Product Type","tags":
        [
          {"id":1,"name":"Smartphone"},
          {"id":1,"name":"Smartphone"}
        ]
      },
      {"id":2,"name":"Brand","tags":
        [
          {"id":2,"name":"Apple"},
          {"id":4,"name":"Samsung"}
        ]
      },
      {"id":3,"name":"Model","tags":
        [
          {"id":3,"name":"iPhone 6"},
          {"id":5,"name":"Galaxy A5"}
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Currently I have only two `products` in the database: "Apple iPhone 6 Smartphone" and "Samsung Galaxy A5 Smartphone". You can see that it outputs the specifications and tags from all products, instead of only the `has_and_belongs_to_many` related ones. The **correct** JSON output for the `item` related to the "Apple iPhone 6 Smartphone" `product` would look like like this:

```
"item":{"id":1,"product":
  {"id":1,"name":"Apple iPhone 6 Smartphone","specifications":
    [
      {"id":1,"name":"Product Type","tags":
        [
          {"id":1,"name":"Smartphone"}
        ]
      },
      {"id":2,"name":"Brand","tags":
        [
          {"id":2,"name":"Apple"}
        ]
      },
      {"id":3,"name":"Model","tags":
        [
          {"id":3,"name":"iPhone 6"}
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Edit:

The problem has nothing to do with how the JSON is outputted. The real question is:

**How can I relate the tags correctly to the respective specifications of the respective product?**

Comment: What version of rails are you using? Have you tried using jbuilder?

Comment: Rails 4.2.3, no I have not tried jbuilder yet, but I have just seen that the gem is already installed in my project. How would I do this with jbuilder?

Comment: I've updated my answer, let me know if that works.

Comment: I have edited my question with Images of the data of the two join tables products_specifications and specifications_tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a (thinking) problem with has_and_belongs_to_many association. I switched to has_many :through associations, and created an extra model/table: "product_specs"

```
  create_table "product_specs", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "product_id"
    t.integer  "specification_id"
    t.integer  "tag_id"
    t.integer  "creator_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",       null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",       null: false
  end
```

now i can easily output the right associations with JBuilder (thanks to @kjmagic13 for pointing it out) like this:

```
json.extract! @item, :id, :condition, :user, :winner
  json.product do
    json.extract! @item.product, :name
    json.product_specs @item.product.product_specs do |spec|
      json.specification spec.specification, :id, :name
      json.tag spec.tag, :id, :name
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use jbuilder. Something along the lines of:

```
# app/views/items/show.json.jbuilder
json.item do
    json.extract! @item, :id
    json.product do
        json.extract! @item.product, :name
        json.specifications @item.product.specifications do |spec|
            json.extract! spec, :name
            json.tags spec.tags, :id, :name
        end
    end
end
```

Be sure to change `item` to an instance variable `@item` in the show method in your Items controller.

Comment: I tried this, but still it gives me (almost) the same JSON output: `{"item":{"id":1,"product":{"name":"Apple iPhone 6 Smartphone","specifications":[{"name":"Product Type","tags":[{"id":1,"name":"Smartphone"},{"id":1,"name":"Smartphone"}]},{"name":"Brand","tags":[{"id":2,"name":"Apple"},{"id":4,"name":"Samsung"}]},{"name":"Model","tags":[{"id":3,"name":"iPhone 6"},{"id":5,"name":"Galaxy A5"}]}]}}}` .. Maybe I did the relations wrong

Comment: Did you remove the render logic from the show controller?

Comment: yes i outcommented it, this JSON output from my previous comment deffinitely comes from the show.json.jbuilder file

Comment: there must be something wrong with the has and belongs to many relationship

Comment: @MuteMinute, I'm taking a shot in the dark here and assuming you're trying to accomplish something along the lines of Ryan Bate's example of Dynamic Forms. Check out his [video on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t_FNKR7jahM). I also recommend you read this great article on [Why You Don’t Need Has_and_belongs_to_many Relationships](http://blog.flatironschool.com/why-you-dont-need-has-and-belongs-to-many/).

Comment: yes, thanks I realized already that its much better to go with has_many and has_many :through associations in this case, thanks for your help anyway!